# Syntax highlighting in Midnight Commander viewer

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mc

I would like to `mc` **viewer** (`mcview`, run by <kbd>F3</kbd> key) highlights my C++ code. Is it possible?

For editing (`mcedit`, <kbd>F4</kbd> key) I am using `vim` with its own syntax highlighting. For viewing, I can't find such option. There is

```
editor_syntax_highlighting=1
```

Which can be changed in `~/.mc/ini` or `~/.config/mc/ini` but it's obviously related with built-in `mcedit`, not the viewer. Is there something like `viewer_syntax_highlighting=1` or any other way how to highlight syntax in viewer?

Comment: This question belongs to AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Viewer doesn't do syntax highlighting, only Editor does.

Comment: Is there a reason behind it?

Comment: I can guess it's simply nobody has implemented it.

Comment: For reference - there is a ticket  proposing this enhancement in the mc bugtracker - http://midnight-commander.org/ticket/28 - However,  it was created already 2005

Comment: It's only a feature request, not a patch. Someone has to step in and implement the feature.

Comment: Would be possible to apply [these patches](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/83) to have an `mcedit` read-only mode that could replace `mcview` by [changing VIEWER](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80852/209677) environment variable